# How to Make Dynamic Website SEO Friendly?

Tags: seo, sitemap, duplicate-content, structured-data, technical-seo

The content of every page on my [website](https://globaltradehelpdesk.org/en) is generated after user input, which in turn modifies the URLs. However, upon accessing the website, only a basic landing page is displayed, and all the advanced and informative content is generated solely by user input.

The generated content pages have minimal differences between them. Additionally, we utilize numerous APIs and some of them result in relatively high loading times.

Google Search Console also identified reasons why pages aren't indexed:

[image]

So, I wonder what actions I can take to enhance my ranking, which is currently close to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is less about a dynamic website being SEO friendly, and just about you reversing/mitigating all the issues you have described:

> high loading times

> content pages have minimal differences between them

From this we can infer the pages are slow (perhaps you can use caching), and thin/poor quality content, which in itself is not good for Google.

You may still rank, but you will want to ensure that your pages offer the most possible value. If they do not offer any value then you might consider blocking them lest they degrade the whole site.

You should also look into internal link strategies, making sure you have a good structure, as well as sitemaps.

Comment: I'd add they they also have to fix the "only a basic landing page is displayed" part.  Once a user creates a page with user input, it needs to get a link from some other page so that search engines know about it and can crawl it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Could you clarify, please? Possibly provide some examples what do you mean. Thanks.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes good point Stephen, the landing page - and without seeing the site - with any dynamic type site where you potentially have 100k-even millions of pages - you absolutely need to think about sitemaps and internal linking strategies at scale.